# boost mpi MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE

Tags: multithreading, boost-mpi

I use mpich with MPI_THREAD_MULTIPLE support. From boost documentation:
 *For variable-length data, e.g., serialized types and packed archives, two messages will be sent via MPI_Send: one containing the length of the data and the second containing the data itself*

Is it safe to send serialized types with same tag, to same rank from different threads? Receive rank has only one thread for receiving messages

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems it does not work. I must use unique tag for each thread.